# lintOptions not being recognized by Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

So, first, some information about my setup. I'm trying to build an app, that includes different modules, in Android Studio. I have the following dependencies in my top-level build.gradle file:

```
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.9.3'
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
       classpath 'org.moallemi.gradle.advanced-build-version:gradle-plugin:1.5.3'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
   }
```

I tried to disable Lint in one of my modules, because I was getting Lint errors that I'll investigate later (for the moment, I just want to get a build going). I used the following setting in one of my modules:

```
android {

    [...]

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    [...]

}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error:(48, 0) No signature of method:
com.android.build.gradle.managed.AndroidConfig.lintOptions() is applicable for argument types:
(build_9pxacuo2f46evz0elkujz25xa$_run_closure1$_closure4$_closure11)
values:[build_9pxacuo2f46evz0elkujz25xa$_run_closure1$_closure4$_closure11@96dc8be]
```

I already researched the appropriate documentation, and things seem to be right:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips.html

What could I be doing wrong here? Many thanks for any help on this matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently I have to write things this way (it is very strange, but I'm able to builld fine now):

```
model {
    android.lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    android {
        // Rest of the other declarations goes here...
    }
}
```

I don't know **why** this is working, I only know that it works. Once I have more time (I'm in a time crunch now) I'll come back to this to see if I can investigate this further and find out the reasons for this weird way to specifying the lintOptions...

Answer (score 0):

Gradle experimental plugin wraps android block into model block and the lintOptions method does not accept closure.

For use android block try this code:

```
model {
    android {

        [...]

        lintOptions.abortOnError false

        [...]
    }
}
```

See the documentation here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing: that snippet of gradle is already inside a 'model'.

Comment: I updated my answer. The lintOptions method does not accept closure.

Comment: Actually, I found out that a different solution than that works. Perhaps yours will work too, but because I need to keep moving forward with my current task, I cannot check that now. Whenever I can check it later, though, I'll upvote your answer.